# Can I create my own CRM company reselling our version of CivicCRM?

Tags: sales

I am looking to create a CRM that I can license to non-profits, that is built on CiviCRM. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you plan on selling licenses to the code? Or perhaps consulting and then hosting fees for the current open source code plus maybe your tweaks to it?

Comment: Yes, but only if you also provide source code and offer that same freedom to users of it.
Probably more realistic to sell hosting and support.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is probably no, but it depends on what the question was.

My reading of section 5 and 6 in the licence as linked by @demerit https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html
means that you can't "license" the code itself, even if you modify it, except by using the Affero license, i.e. you can't charge money for it.

What you can do and what others do is to earn money by providing additional value over and above the code base in some way, typically some version of hosting and/or support.

Conclusion: earning money by selling/renting the code is not allowed, even if you modify it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a lawyer, but the gist is that yes you can, but people will expect you to make your modifications available to download.

The license is AGPL 3, which is detailed at https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html.

Comment: Thank you. I am mostly interested to know if it is technically possibly, meaning does the existing technology allow for that type of technical execution.

Comment: Yes, you can download the full code either in release form at https://civicrm.org/download, or in source form from the git repositories at https://github.com/civicrm. Or you can look at a developer setup with https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit and then build extensions to the system following the documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/

Answer (score 1):

Yes; there are many companies that do exactly that.  Some market their CRM under the CiviCRM name; others specialize and rebrand (e.g. JVillage sells ShulSuite, a CiviCRM configured for synagogues).